# Adding pixels to a vector

Tags: matlab, vector

I have the following function in `matlab`.

```
function s = value(x, y)
            for i=1:length(y)
                for j=1:length(y)
                    if y(i,j) ~= 0.5;
                        pixels = x(i,j);
                    end
                end
            end
            pixels
        end
```

When I run it, I just get the **last** pixel in the results. How can I get the vector of *all* results?

Thanks.

Comment: Why write a function with a return value if you never assign it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to keep an index:

```
function pixels = value(x, y)

pIndex = 1;

for i=1:length(y)
   for j=1:length(y)
      if y(i,j) ~= 0.5;
         pixels(pIndex) = x(i,j);
         pIndex = pIndex + 1;
      end
   end
end

pixels

end
```

However, you should vectorise your code to make it more efficient and easy to read, that function could be replaced by:

```
pixels = x(y ~= 0.5)
```

Answer (score 1):

`pixels(end+1)=x(i,j)` adds the value on the right after the last element of the vector on the left.

But what about  `s = x(y~=0.5)` or something like this? There surely is a vectorized solution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What is `end` here? Can you kindly clarify how to use it? And, yes, I know about `s = x(y~=0.5)`, but just want to compare with the `if-statement` way...

Comment: erm...`end` is the end of the vector, i.e. the index of the last element in the respective direction. `help end` is helpful, too (third paragraph).

Comment: `pixels(end+1)=x(i,j)` is the same as `pixels = [pixels x(i,j)]`. Instead of overwriting `pixels`, you append it with each new result

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with matlab, but you seem to be overwriting `pixels` each iteration.

Rather than replacing the value of `pixels` each iteration with `pixels = x(i,j);`, is there anything along the lines of `pixels += x(i,j);` you can do?

If `pixels` is not just a value however, but rather an array or similar data structure, you need to update the index for each iteration so that the value is stored separately from the previous iteration's, such that it does not overwrite the value from before.